# Selenium Webdriver - Issue with FirefoxDriver: Error: cannot open display: :0.0

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I made a test case in selenium which  automatically opens Firefox and do its login stuffs. I made this using java programming through Eclipse.& i tested it is working fine in my windows7 system.

And Now, **the problem is** A cron job starts this same program in the server, which throws the following error when trying to open firefox:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
 ------------- Standard Error -----------------
 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055       after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
 Error: cannot open display: :0.0
 Error: cannot open display: :0.0

    at             org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnectio n.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at com.lo.test.selenium.AssignCampaignTestCase.<clinit>(AssignCampaignTestCase.java:42)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:375)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeInVM(JUnitTask.java:1420)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:848)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1899)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
  ------------- ---------------- ---------------

    Caused an ERROR
 null
```

I have installed xvfb & selenuim in my server. I checked they are running.
And i [followed this tutorial](http://www.danstraw.com/installing-selenium-server-2-as-a-service-on-ubuntu/2010/09/23/)

& my testCase Example is

```
        package com.lo.test.selenium; 
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
    import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    import javax.mail.Flags;
    import javax.mail.Folder;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Store; 
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

   public class MyExampleTestCase {

  private static ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("global-messages");
  static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //Make it static in order to make one    
      instance of this class(helps to avoid opening of 2 browsers at once)

  @Test

  public void campaignEmailTestCase() throws InterruptedException { 
 MyExampleTestCase emTesObj=new MyExampleTestCase ();  
 String fName="test LO";
    Integer LeadId=570903;
    String campaignName="2Get"; 
    String SubjName="Welcome";   //NOTE: No problem,Type without 
   double quotes. It will work for you 
    emTesObj.doLogin(); 
    emTesObj.goToLeadsListPage();
    emTesObj.searchByFirstName(fName);//without this also,it will work but Gives you the correct 
     navigation on UI
    emTesObj.waitBeforePageLoads(LeadId.toString()); //pass the Id attribute which you aspect to 
     see after the page is loaded
    emTesObj.assignCampaign(LeadId, campaignName);  
    emTesObj.readRecentEmail(SubjName);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this when you run your code on a local machine:

```
private WebDriver driver = null;

public void open() throws Exception
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

And this when you run your code on a remote server:

```
private WebDriver driver = null;

public void openHeadless() throws Exception
{
    FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/usr/local/bin/firefox"));
    binary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY",System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id",":99"));
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary,null);
}
```

Comment: i checked my directory "/usr/local/bin/"  there is no firefox inside the "bin" folder. Does this solve my above problem?? . In above code, I updated my localhost Testcase class.Please look at it. Where should i implement your code?

Comment: Use the `openHeadless` code when you run your program on the remote server. Find the path of Firefox **on the remote server**, and change `/usr/local/bin/firefox` to that path.

Comment: It's not a built-in method. I meant for you to take the code in the `openHeadless` method and use it instead of your `driver = new FirefoxDriver()` initialization.

Comment: Okay as you said i placed the code but still its showing error like:    `org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: cannot open display: :99
Error: cannot open display: :99 ......`

Comment: Are you trying this on your local-host, or on the remote server? If on your local-host, have you properly installed `xvfb` on it?

Comment: This answer helped me to realize that I needed to stop trying to run my tests remotely and just run them locally on the machine (I have it hooked up to a monitor and keyboard/mouse). I didn't have to modify the DISPLAY env var and everything just started working.

Comment: I installed `xvfb` but still have the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Selenium node in headless mode with xvfb-run command like the following...

```
$ xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1280x1600x24" java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node
```

...then you may encounter the same symptoms because of **xvfb process crash**. Here's how the process tree looks like in this case:

```
├─sh -e /proc/self/fd/9
│   └─xvfb-run /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s -screen 0 1280x1600x24 java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node
│       ├─Xvfb :104 -screen 0 1280x1600x24
│       │   └─4*[{Xvfb}]
│       └─java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node
│           └─27*[{java}]
```

Xvfb process in this tree by default restarts for each browser launch (see **-reset** option documentation) and for some reason has memory leaks. So when you use the node during days and hours memory leaks cause Xvfb process to crash but java process with Selenium node stays intact. In this situation browser being launched by Selenium can't open display because xvfb is not running and you're seeing the error message.

To solve the issue you need to turn off xvfb restart behavior which is done by **-noreset** option:

```
$ xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1280x1600x24 -noreset" java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using selenium with maven ,just update dependencies in the pom.xml file and it will fix the issue. It worked for me. 
If you are using test unit,update the jars used to the latest version :)